# Compare mov files using spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to spark,and am able to compare two image files, but dont know how to compare two mov files if not matched extra records load into another file with the unmatched records.

Please find my code to compare img files

```
private static boolean compareImages(File trgtFile, File srcFile) {
        try {
            // take buffer data from botm image files //
            BufferedImage biA = ImageIO.read(trgtFile);
            DataBuffer dbA = biA.getData().getDataBuffer();
            int sizeA = dbA.getSize();
            BufferedImage biB = ImageIO.read(srcFile);
            DataBuffer dbB = biB.getData().getDataBuffer();
            int sizeB = dbB.getSize();
            // compare data-buffer objects //
            if (sizeA == sizeB) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sizeA; i++) {
                    if (dbA.getElem(i) != dbB.getElem(i)) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to compare image files ..." + trgtFile.getName() + " ::: and :::" + srcFile.getName());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Please help

Comment: Why is this tagged Scala?

Comment: I think, spark and scala goes hand-in-hand.